# SQL: Could this issue need two many-to-many relationships between the same two tables?

Tags: sql, database

I'm working on a homework problem.

I'm given the following entities: COMPANY, OPENING, QUALIFICATION, CANDIDATE, JOB_HISTORY, PLACEMENT, COURSE and SESSION.

- Every course develops one specific qualification; however, TEC does
  not offer a course for every qualification. Some qualifications are
  developed through multiple courses.
- Some courses cover advanced topics that require specific
  qualifications as prerequisites. Some courses cover basic topics that
  do not require any prerequisite qualifications. A course can have
  several prerequisites. A qualification can be a prerequisite for more
  than one course.

Doesn't this sound like 2 different many-to-many  relationships between COURSE and QUALIFICATION?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prerequisites requirement is a many-to-many relationship.

But the fact that each qualification may be developed through multiple courses doesn't mean that any course can develop multiple qualifications.  In fact, you specifically say that each course develops only one qualification.  So this is not a many-to-many relationship.

This is a many-to-one.  That is, COURSE contains a column referencing QUALIFICATION.  Thus only one qualification per course.  But multiple rows in COURSE may reference the same QUALIFICATION, which is still many-to-one.